# read file and folders without using a nested loop

Tags: python

I have over 100,000 files spread across multiple directories and right now i can read names and path to each file using nested `for` loop, like this,

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('python/Lib/email'):
     for file in files:
        # some work here
```

is there anyway to achieve this without using a nested loop? it is taking longer than we expected to read the amount of files we have

Comment: If the final problem is time consuming , maybe you could try to code it in way of parallel processing.

Comment: not sure if it's any faster but you could try the `glob` module.

Comment: @MatrixTai Python _does_ have real parallel processing. You can run multiple I/O-bound threads in parallel, you can run multiple threads doing work in libraries like NumPy in parallel, or of course you can run multiple processes instead of threads in parallel.

Comment: What makes you think the nested loop has anything to do with anything here? It's incredibly unlikely, since you're ultimately iterating once per file, the same way you would if the loop were flat. And, while iterating a list isn't quite free in Python, it's a lot faster than calling stat on all of the files in a directory, much less whatever actual work you're doing.

Comment: Meanwhile, what version of Python are you using? If it's not 3.5 or later, you should consider getting the `scandir` backport, because it can be a lot faster than the `listdir`-based implementation of `walk` in older Python. Or, depending on your platform, `fts` may be even faster (although you may have to use `ctypes` or `cffi` or Cython…). But that's all assuming that it's just walking the 100K files that's slow, as opposed to the `# some work here`. You really need to profile your code before you put a lot of work into optimizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if problem is the additional loop after opening for then:

```
import os

for fpath in (os.path.join(root, fname)
              for root, dirs, files
              in os.walk(R"python/Lib/email")
              for fname
              in files):
    pass  # do something with the path
```

Execution time can be reduced in many ways that depend on what you are doing in the "some work" block.
If you do a lot of additional filesystem checks, you could, for example, wrap fpath in pathlib.Path().

I suggest using cProfile module to find out what is slowing your code down.